# How to override magento theme layout file

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, overrides

I am a newbie to `Magento 2.2.4` and i want to get bootstrap 4 css and my own js files.. As a first step trying to override the theme layout file.

I created a theme and enabled it successfully. (All js and css call are routed to my theme). The theme is inherited from magento-blank theme

Now i am trying to override the parent blank theme with my theme layout following this guide
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

I am getting the following error :

> Trying to override modular view file 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/app/design/frontend/TridentTechnominds/store/TridentTechnominds_Theme/layout/override/theme/magento/blank/default_head_blocks.xml'
>   for theme 'magento/blank', which is not ancestor of theme
>   'TridentTechnominds/store'

I tried all methods like :

> 1. theme/Magento/theme-frontend-blank/default_head_blocks.xml => getting error over here
> 2. theme/Magento/frontend-blank/default_head_blocks.xml
> 3. theme/Magento/blank/default_head_blocks.xml => getting error over here
> 4. theme/magento/theme-frontend-blank/default_head_blocks.xml

Kindly guide me the right folder structure. I have been just making and googling for **6 hours** now.

Attached is the folder structure...[image]

Update 1:

My mistake in naming convention of the folder. The blue underlined folder name was changed.

Even then, the trident.css is getting loaded from position black underlined i.e. under layout folder.

If i take it inside theme/magento/blank it doesnt work.
Note: I tried Magento as foldername too.

Attaching the updated folder structure.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override **layout** from parent theme, here in your case `default_head_blocks.xml` from `Magento/blank` :

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themeName}/Magento_Theme/layout/override/theme/Magento/blank/default_head_blocks.xml
```

More information in [Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html).

Comment: I figured out the naming convention error. The folder name should be Magento_Theme but i gave as TridentTechnominds_Theme which caused the error. But still the theme is not overriding, but still i am getting the error. I will update my question shortly

Comment: Please try exactly my path

Answer (score 0):

Your theme should have the blank theme as the parent.
app/design/frontend/TridentTechnominds/TridentTechnominds_Theme/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>TridentTechnominds Theme</title>
<parent>Magento/blank</parent>
<media>
    <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
</media>
```

By using below structure in the theme you can do changes to the xml file of Magento_Theme module.
app
  design
    frontend
      TridentTechnominds (namespace - recommends to use lowercase)
        TridentTechnominds_Theme (theme - recommends to use lowercase)
          Magento_Theme
            layout
              default_head_blocks.xml

If you want to override the file in blank theme itself use the structure mentioned in @Prince's comment below.