# Magento2.2.5 : Layout override not taking priority over Magento_blank theme layout

Tags: magento2, layout, theme

I am new to Magento 2 and, to begin with, I try to change the header from default Magento_Theme. But I am stuck here.

I followed the doc to create my own theme in `app/design/frontend/<my_vendor>/<my_theme_name>`.

This theme has Magento/blank as parent in theme.xml.
This seems to work well as I can define website theme to `<my_theme_name>` in the admin panel.

Then, I tried to override the default Magento_Theme layout.
I copied `vendor/magento/module-theme/frontend/layout/default.xml` into my theme folder under `app/design/frontend/<my_vendor>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`.

And to check if that worked, I tried to hide the Header, using the `remove` attribute as following :
`<referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true">`.

This remove doesn't work, whereas it works well when I put the same remove attribute into the default.xml file from the Magento_Theme folder...

The thing is I don't understand why my theme layout seems to not take the priority over the Magento_Theme layout.
Could it be something about modules order in `app/etc/config.php` ?

I use `php bin/magento cache:flush` to clear my cache after each modification.

Update : After seeing this [stack exchange issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227246/how-to-override-magento-theme-layout-file) I tried to put
my custom layout under `app/design/frontend/<my_vendor>/<my_theme_name>/Magento_Theme/layout/override/theme/Magento/blank/default.xml` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used  this at custom theme (app/design/frontend/[custom_vendor]/[custom_theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml ) and clear cache,And found that its working.